# mod_rewrite: multiple domains on one server, mod_rewrite refuses to work on one

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite, virtualhost

I have a server that serves several domains from a single IP address using Apache's Virtual Host shenanigans. Three of the sites are required to redirect to `www` if it's omitted from the URL.

I have the following rule in the `.htaccess` file of each domain:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\..+$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
```

This works for two of the three, but the third completely fails to comply. I know that the `.htaccess` is being hit because the framework requires all hits to be routed through `index.php`... and that is happening correctly. So, it's not permissions, and the `.htaccess` is identical (more or less) on each domain. I even looked into caching (even though that doesn't make any sense... desperation gives way to insanity!)

Please help me if you have any clue what is going on.

As requested, here's the complete `vhost` config, and `.htaccess` file...

`vhost` configuration:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerAdmin me@gmail.com
        DocumentRoot /var/www/example.com
        ServerName www.example.com
        <Directory />
                Options FollowSymLinks
                AllowOverride None
        </Directory>
        <Directory /var/www/example.com>
                Options FollowSymLinks MultiViews
                AllowOverride None
                Order allow,deny
                allow from all
        </Directory>

        ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log

        LogLevel warn

        CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

`.htaccess` file:

```
# BEGIN example.com

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>

RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\..+$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]

RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^.*$ - [S=40]

####################################################
# If requested URL-path plus ".php" exists as a file
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/$1.php -f
# Rewrite to append ".php" to extensionless URL-path
RewriteRule ^(([^/]+/)*[^.]+)$ /$1.php [L]
####################################################

# redirect to RoutingHandler
RewriteRule ^.*$ /index.php [NC,L]

</IfModule>

# END example.com
```

Bear in mind, there are two other domains set up in an identical manner... and they both work with zero issues.

Comment: It looks fine... except the `www` issue. I've taken great pains to make sure it's serving the right code. I know how easy it is to mess up vhost configs.

Comment: I even tried a version of the regex that explicitly mentioned the domain... `^domain\.com$`... no luck. It's just `domain.com`, nothing special. I'm completely stumped.

Comment: Maybe if you update your question with complete information about the domain, including the relevant vhost configuration and other code in the respective .htaccess file, somebody might be able to find out what's the problem.

Comment: Hmmm... nothing but crickets huh?

Comment: I think the problem is this "*...there are two other domains set up in an identical manner... and they both work with zero issues.*", which means `AllowOverride` is also set to `None` in those domains. But, Apache documentation contains the following statement about the [AllowOverride](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/core.html#allowoverride) directive:
"*When this directive is set to None, then .htaccess files are completely ignored. In this case, the server will not even attempt to read .htaccess files in the filesystem.*"

Comment: That's a great theory, and I thank you for your time. However, there is a logical flaw in your suggestion: if I have two other domains set up in the same manner (which you maintain should also not work) then why do they perform as expected? Also, just because I'm a fair judge, I tried the appropriate changes. No dice.

Comment: Agree. Not my suggestion, though, Apache's (The link to the doc is in my previous comment). But that's exactly the problem I wanted to point out. Thought that information could be useful.

Comment: Yeah, thanks and all... I'm very familiar with Apache which is why this is so frustrating. This is just weird. It feels like it's cached on the DNS side... maybe it is!

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old question, but google brought me here while looking for answers on the same problem.
After searching through apache's documentation I found:
[AllowOverride Directive](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/core.html#allowoverride)

> When this directive is set to None, then .htaccess files are completely ignored. In this case, the server will not even attempt to read .htaccess files in the filesystem.

So I changed "AllowOverride None" to "AllowOverride All" in the `<Directory /var/www/example.com>` section and it worked.